# c++ string in for loop makes length 0

Tags: c++, string, loops, for-loop, iostream

I have the following code, for some reason when I try to use a `for loop` to declare  `string attribs` from `string wholecommand`, `attribs.length()` returns `0` and

When i try:

`cout<<attribs;`

It outputs nothing.

```
for(int q=0;q<wholecommand.length();q++){
    cout<<atrribs[q];  
}
```

The code above is the only way i can get output. What is wrong with my code and how can I get it to output data without using a for loop?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;   

int main(){
    string wholecommand="apple";
    string atrribs; 
    for(int a=0;a<wholecommand.length();a++){  
        atrribs[a]= wholecommand[a];           
    }                                               

    cout<<"Content of Wholecommand: "<<wholecommand<<endl;  //returns apple
    cout<<"Length of Wholecommand: "<<wholecommand.length()<<endl; //returns 5

    cout<<"Content of attributes: "<<atrribs<<endl;  ////////contains nothing
    cout<<"Length of attributes: "<<atrribs.length()<<endl; ////////returns 0

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Why not just assign?  `string attribs = wholecommand;`?

Comment: If you want to copy `string wholecommand = "apple"` to `string atrribs` then you can do this `string stribs = wholecommand;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a

```
atrribs.resize(wholecommand.length());
```

before the `for()` loop to get this working properly.
You cannot assign values via `std::string` indices, where the target string wasn't resized to match them.

Though it's questionable, what's the purpose of your code sample as is at all? You can simply achieve the same with

```
atrribs = wholecommand;
```

without that `for()` loop.

Comment: Works Great!!! And for your question: I wanted a way to separate attributes from a command string to run in cmd pipes, this is the portion of the code that wasn't working. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

attribs is constructed as a string of length 0; that's what the default ctor does.  Naturally when you print a string of length 0, nothing shows up.  (Even if you got around the problem of referring to elements with indices past that size.)

To make it behave, make sure it's long enough:  either set it equal to something big enough (`attrib = wholeCommand` -- and then you're done!); or resize it; or call it with a ctor to make it big enough (`string attrib (5, 'x'); // gives it 5 copies of x`).

And as Paul points out above:  you *could* just say string attrib = wholeCommand; and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
string atrribs(wholecommand.length(), 0);
```

From [version six](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) of the string constructor, this string constructor takes as the first argument the number of consecutive characters to fill and as the second argument what characters to fill.  In this example, atrribs is filled with the null character (0) five consecutive times.  I could have used any character in this example.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could *edit your answer* and provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Answer (score 0):

In the first answer to this question, a resize() was suggested as a solution.

Given the code pattern, assuming that is what you really want to do, resize() adds in a bit of wasted work. You are overwriting each position in attribs. In that case, the work done by resize in growing the string and default constructing the elements is useless.

attribs.reserve() could be better. Of course, you can't use "[a] = " any more.